# JavaFX wizard for configurations?

Tags: java

I searched in internet for wizard with many steps or many pages but couldn't find a good one.

Basically looking for a wizard with many levels (atleast 6) example: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-Components/DynamicWizardDialog.htm

could someone help me with a good example or snippet to build a good wizard for providing the user to create configurations required for the application?

example,

```
Level 1. DB connection details
Level 2. FTP server details
Level 3. Directory Mapping details
Level 4. Third Party Server details
...
...
```

Also, i would like to save each level to each configuration file or appending to a single configuration xml for further modifications.

Please help me with your thoughts/suggestions.

Comment: Do you want dialogs in JavaFX, or do you just want to write to a XML/other file to save the configuration?

Comment: I want the dialogs in JavaFx with the above as Wizards...so user can enter the configuration details and say "Next" or "Save" (OR) "Next", "Next" and finally finish

Comment: Which version of JavaFX are you using?

Comment: Any version is fine for me, Gilian..

Comment: There is a wizard api in [ControlsFX](http://controlsfx.bitbucket.org/org/controlsfx/dialog/Wizard.html) with [sample code](https://bitbucket.org/controlsfx/controlsfx/src/91d7a2d0aaf5926a695db3f1446a09283e76d26f/controlsfx-samples/src/main/java/org/controlsfx/samples/dialogs/HelloDialogs.java?at=default#HelloDialogs.java-572).  I have not used it and cannot comment on it, but you could investigate it for your purposes.

Answer (score 0):

For the dialogs look at this link: http://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-dialogs-official/

And you want to Save configurations, well there are a number of options. You could make a class which Contains configuration settings and serialise, or you could export settings to a file (xml, normal text, etc) when the configuration might get changed externally from the program use xml or a text file

Comment: for the dialogs, the above link is fine. How about the wizard ? i'm still not clear

Comment: You mean adding multiple panes to the dialog which get linked together?

Comment: Basically multiple configuration inputs needs to be collected from the user. either Multiple panes or multiple wizard with next, previous and finish button or something better which is easy navigation and flexible for change..

Comment: What's the exact question? You could create a pane inside a JavaFX dialog with a card layout to scroll though the questions and append the specific data to a configuration file?